# How to align:center <row><key>'s elements? (xml android)

Tags: android, html, xml

I'm typing on Android keyboard, I can't center the 2nd line (asdf...)
1nd line (qwerty) 10 keys -> 10%p width regular
2nd line (asdf) 9 keys -> 9 keys+empty space inthe end
I WANT THIS
2nd line (asdf) 9 keys -> 5%p space+(9 x keys)+5%p space

I tried to add a empty key element and a button but it doesn't work

[see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6LUp.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:horizontalGap="1dp"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:keyHeight="50dp"
    android:verticalGap="1dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp">

    <Row>
        <Key

            android:codes="113"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="q" />
        <Key
            android:codes="119"
            android:keyLabel="w" />
        <Key
            android:codes="101"
            android:keyLabel="e" />
        <Key
            android:codes="114"
            android:keyLabel="r" />
        <Key
            android:codes="116"
            android:keyLabel="t" />
        <Key
            android:codes="121"
            android:keyLabel="y" />
        <Key
            android:codes="117"
            android:keyLabel="u" />
        <Key
            android:codes="105"
            android:keyLabel="i" />
        <Key
            android:codes="111"
            android:keyLabel="o" />
        <Key
            android:codes="112"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="p" />
    </Row>
__________________________________________MAIN_THREAD!!!!!_____________
    ***<Row>
<!--        <Key-->
<!--            android:keyWidth="5%p"-->
<!--            android:keyHeight="50dp"-->
<!--            android:codes=" "-->
<!--            android:keyLabel=" "-->
<!--            />-->
<!--        <Button-->
<!--            android:layout_width="5dp">-->
**<!--        </Button>-->*****

________________________________________[enter image description here][1]____________________________________________________________

        <Key
            android:codes="97"
            android:keyLabel="a" />
        <Key
            android:codes="115"
            android:keyLabel="s" />
        <Key
            android:codes="100"
            android:keyLabel="d" />
        <Key
            android:codes="102"
            android:keyLabel="f" />
        <Key
            android:codes="103"
            android:keyLabel="g" />
        <Key
            android:codes="104"
            android:keyLabel="h" />
        <Key
            android:codes="106"
            android:keyLabel="j" />
        <Key
            android:codes="107"
            android:keyLabel="k" />
        <Key
            android:codes="108"
            android:keyLabel="l" />
    </Row>

    <Row >
        <Key
            android:codes="-1"
            android:keyWidth="15%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="UP"/>
        <Key
            android:codes="122"
            android:keyLabel="z" />
        <Key
            android:codes="120"
            android:keyLabel="x" />
        <Key
            android:codes="99"
            android:keyLabel="c" />
        <Key
            android:codes="118"
            android:keyLabel="v" />
        <Key
            android:codes="98"
            android:keyLabel="b" />
        <Key
            android:codes="110"
            android:keyLabel="n" />
        <Key
            android:codes="109"
            android:keyLabel="m" />
        <Key
            android:codes="-5"
            android:isRepeatable="true"
            android:keyWidth="15%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="DEL" />
    </Row>

    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key
            android:codes="44"
            android:keyWidth="15%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_special_chars"
            android:keyLabel="'123" />

        <Key
            android:codes="44"
            android:keyWidth="10%p"
            android:keyLabel="," />

        <Key
            android:codes="32"
            android:isRepeatable="true"
            android:keyWidth="40%p"
            android:keyLabel="SPACE" />
        <Key
            android:codes="46"
            android:keyLabel="." />
        <Key
            android:codes="-4"
            android:keyWidth="20%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="DONE" />
    </Row>


</Keyboard>
```

I'm typing on Android keyboard, I can't center the 2nd line (asdf...)
1nd line (qwerty) 10 keys -> 10%p width regular
2nd line (asdf) 9 keys -> 9 keys+empty space inthe end
I WANT THIS
2nd line (asdf) 9 keys -> 5%p space+(9 x keys)+5%p space

I tried to add a empty key element and a button but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know if there is a screenshot added to the question, here is the link
https://pasteboard.co/lmDvK1CMCLAm.png